# Python if check error

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use the code:

```
def Jack():
    global PHand
    if 11 or 24 or 37 or 50 in PHand:
        PHand.remove(11 or 24 or 37 or 50)
        PHand.append("Jack")
```

I get an error saying list.remove(x) x is not in PHand, my question is, shouldn't the if check prevent this error?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What's special about those numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're basically checking to see whether `11` is true. It's non-zero, so your `if` always executes. What you want is:

```
if 11 in PHand or 24 in PHand or 37 in PHand or 50 in Phand:
```

Of course, your `PHand.remove` always tries to remove `11` for much the same reason. You can't tell `remove` to remove *any* of those (not sure where you got the idea that would even work, it's not in any documentation I've ever seen), so you should structure it so:

```
if 11 in PHand:
   PHand.remove(11)
   PHand.append("Jack")
if 24 in PHand:
   PHand.remove(24)
   PHand.append("Jack")
```

... and so on.

Of course you'd be better off refactoring that into a loop or even a function, rather than repeating all that code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate over each element:

```
for i in (11, 24, 37, 50):   # assign i to 11, then 24, then 37, then 50
    if i in PHand:           # check each one in PHand
        PHand.remove(i)      # and remove that one
        PHand.append("Jack") # your code
        break                # end the loop. remove this to check all
```

Otherwise, `11 or 24 or 37 or 50 in PHand` outputs `11`. Try it!

```
>>> 11 or 24 or 37 or 50 in PHand
11
```

Why? the way `or` works, it checks if the first side is truthy. If it is, it doesn't bother evaluating the rest, since the result couldn't change. If it weren't truthy, it would move on to the next argument, and so on.

And what of the `in PHand`? That actually gets evaluated first, to just the last number like this:

```
11 or 24 or 37 or (50 in PHand)
```

But again, 11 short-circuits all the `or`s.

---

Long story short:

**or always returns a single value**, not all values at once applied to functions repeatedly or however your syntax implies.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of solving it using filter:

```
  def Jack():
      T = [11,24,37,50]
      found = filter(lambda x:x in T, PHand)
      if found:
          [PHand.remove(x) for x in found]
          PHand.append('Jack')

  PHand = range(10,55)
  Jack()
```